# php exception try catch in procedural way

Tags: php, try-catch

I want to know if it's possible to use try catch in procedural way to find exceptions and do some thing when I catch them like this: make sure if picture is uploaded then try to resize the picture if the resize function had a problem like (memory_limit) remove the picture.

```
 if(move-uploaded-file($_FILES['name']['tmp_name'], "folder/image.png"){
    try{
       resizeimage("folder/image.png", "folder/image.png");
    }catch(Exception $e){
       unlink("folder/image.png");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is the code you want to use, the Exception object in the catch will become available if the try{} errors and you will have access to it's methods. http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php.  The way you handle the error with the Exception methods is the only part of the code that will be object oriented. Everything inside the catch can be as procedural as you like.

Comment: Sorry, everything inside the try{} can be as procedural as you like.

Comment: thanks a lot, if i have a fatal error (like : memory_limit), this error will be catched or not??

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/exception.getmessage.php

In your case, if you have in your catch $e->getMessage(); and for your scenario it will return something like: "Attempted to allocate x amount of memory but failed"